# Using sqlite in framework

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, xcode7.1

I am creating a framework in swift and I need to use **sqlite**.

I've  imported `#import <sqlite3.h>` to use it and I am writing it in **.h** file created by Xcode.

But while building, I am getting this error:

`"include of non modular header inside framework module"`.

I have searched for this question but couldn't find an appropriate answer that solves my problem.

Comment: Have you added sqlite3 framework by Build Phase-> Link binary->Sqlite3.. in your project?

Comment: Can you add #import < sqlite3.h > in your Bridging-Header.h file:

Comment: In framework you can't use Bridging-Header. It will give error. <unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported

Answer (score 4):

To use SQLite in a custom framework, you need to include the sqlite3.h file directly into the project and then make that file public.

- To get the .h file, right-click on Xcode and select "show package contents"
- In the search bar, type "sqlite3.h"
- Select Xcode in the search area

[image: Finder Search]

- Drag the file to your project and choose "Copy items if needed"
- Select the sqlite3.h file in your project navigator
- In the utilities pane, change target membership to public.

[image: xcode]

In your umbrella header file, make sure you add this line:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```

(Don't use the `<sqlite3.h>` form as you're now including the file from your project)

You may notice that the umbrella header automatically adds the line `#import <UIKit/UIKIt.h>` as shown below. If you don't need UIKit, then remove that line.

[image: Umbrella header]

You can find a full example here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ALBNoSQLDB

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was adding **sqlite3.h** explicitly. It won't be automatically added when you add **libsqlite3.tbd** library. Make **sqlite3.h** public and then import it as umbrella header.

Comment: how to make it public? When I go to build phrases and try to include sqlite3.h it shows only "sqlite3.tbd"

Comment: same problem. How can I make it public?